# Background image not showing in jumbotron

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm running Ruby 1.9.3 on Rails 3.2.21. 
I've added the jumbotron class to the top of my idex.html.erb file.

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1>Handcrafted items from <br>
    around the world.</h1>
  <h2>Discover one-of-a-kind items</h2>
</div>
```

Then in my **custom.css.scss** file, I've added the info for the background image:

```
@import "bootstrap";

body {
    background-color: #F5F5F1;
    color: #333333;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar-default {
    background-color: #EFEFEB;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    font-family: guardian-egyptt, georgia, serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #d5641c;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #0192B5;
}

.center {
    text-align: center;
}

.col-md-3:nth-child(4n+1) {
    clear: left;
}

.col-md-6 {
    h3 {font-size: 45px;}
    h5 {font-size: 25px;}
    p {font-size: 18px;}
}

.caption {
    h3 {
        font-size: 17px;
        margin: 2px;
    }
    p {
        font-size: 15px;
        margin: 0px;
    }
}

.jumbotron {
    background-image: url('jumbotron.jpg');

}
```

The file `jumbotron.jpg` has been saved to the `app/assets/images` folder as instructed. This worked for the instructor, and his jumbotron now displays the background image selected, but mine does not. Mine is just a box with the text in it, and the image is not there.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Steve Chesnowitz's answer should be the right one. Just be aware that when using `background-image: asset-url('your_image.png')` rails will trace the path directly to the images-folder so there is no need to write the full path.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I got the background image to show, but that was only by adding it inline in the `index.html.erb` file.

That code is now:

`<div class="jumbotron" style="background-image: url('jumbotron.jpg');">
  <h1>Handcrafted items from <br>
    around the world.</h1>
  <h2>Discover one-of-a-kind items</h2>
</div>`

But I can't get the fonts to change.

Answer (score 0):

Can the line in your `custom.css.scss` to:

```
.jumbotron {
    background-image: image-url("jumbotron.jpg");
}
```

Red more about building urls in css files with the asset pipeline: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-sass

Comment: I tried that. Same result, the image still isn't showing.

Comment: What URL is generated in the css file? What the URL of that file in your manifest file on the server? Did you compile the assets when deploying to the server?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm very much a noob at this. This is my first application with RoR. I don't understand what you're asking. The files are here if this helps: https://github.com/crista-b/etsydemo

Answer (score 0):

I also only managed to add the background image as inline in the HTML code of

```
 <div class="jumbotron" style="background-image:url('images/imageName.jpg'); background-position:right; background-repeat:no-repeat;">
```

Adding the background-image property to any of hte CSS files didn't work (I changed the ' to " for that and any other combination too).  I tried bootstrap.min.css, jumbotron-narrow.css, creating my onwn style sheet and calling it after any other CSS...

nothing else worked for me!  :-(

Answer (score 0):

```
.jumbotron {
    background: #000 url("image.jpg") center center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your CSS put this code.  setting "asset-url" seems to do the trick.  Hope this if helpful.

```
.jumbotron {
  background-image: asset-url("name_of_image.PNG");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and just discovered a solution. I used a div class="container-fluid" INSIDE the jumbotron and added my image to it. For some reason only inline styling seems to work so I added all my styling inline.

My code reads thus:

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="background-image: 
    url('JumbotronPic.png');
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 100vh;">blah blah blah </div>
```